# mysql date input

Tags: mysql, date

I have a database table--> date field and the date format is yyyy-mm-dd

if i input in anouther format then field show 0000-00-00

what is the problem and how i can overcome this whereas i have use no form encode method??

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using int(32) for your date field and storing unixtime. That way you can format your date into any type of string you want to display.

> [UNIX_TIMESTAMP()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp)

It's called and the you can do this in your query.

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`date`) VALUES (UNIX_TIMESTAMP());
```

You can parse unixtime in any language, and many (like PHP) have built it parsing of unixtime.

```
date("Y-m-d", $row["time"]); // YYYY-MM-DD
```

Comment: This also makes it easier for date calculations (ie if($date1 < $date2) { print "date1 was before date2!"} );

Answer (score 1):

Insert dates in YYYY-MM-DD (ISO format) and when retrieving the date, you may convert it to any format you like using:

```
DATE_FORMAT()
```

Reference:

[DATE_FORMAT(date,format)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).